# Showing an Alert after presenting a Sheet

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a SwiftUI-View `MyView`, that is presenting a view controller when a button is clicked. The presented view controller (implemented in UIKit and wrapped via `UIViewControllerRepresentable` in `MyPresentedView` ) gets a binding to `isShowingAlert` to indicate an error situation which should be handled by showing an alert after the sheet is dismissed.

```
struct MyView: View {
    @State private var isShowingSheet = false
    @State private var isShowingAlert = false

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: { self.isShowingSheet.toggle() }) {
            Text("Show Sheet")
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isShowingSheet) {
            MyPresentedView(alert: self.$isShowingAlert)
        }
        .alert(isPresented: $isShowingAlert) {
            Alert(title: Text("title"), message: Text("message"), dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")))
        }
    }
}
```

**The problem**: since the presented view controller toggles `isShowingAlert` while it is still presented, SwiftUI seems to try to present the alert while the sheet is still presented. This results in log messages like:

> Warning: Attempt to present <SwiftUI.PlatformAlertController ...>  on ... which is already presenting (null)

Is there a proper way to delay the `.alert` until after `.sheet` is dismissed?

Comment: I came up with a potential solution: introduce a new `@State` Bool-flag to allow the view controller to indicate errors and propagate changes of this flag in a `onDismiss` closure to `isShowingAlert`. This way the alert will be presented only after the sheet is dismissed.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record, here is a sketch of the potential solution I mentioned in my comment:

```
struct MyView: View {
    @State private var isShowingSheet   = false
    @State private var errorDuringSheet = false
    @State private var isShowingAlert   = false

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: { self.isShowingSheet.toggle() }) {
            Text("Show Sheet")
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isShowingSheet, onDismiss: propagateError) {
            MyPresentedView(alert: self.$errorDuringSheet)
        }
        .alert(isPresented: $isShowingAlert) {
            Alert(title: Text("title"), message: Text("message"), dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")))
        }
    }

    func propagateError() {
        isShowingAlert   = errorDuringSheet
        errorDuringSheet = false
    }
}
```

Any better solution is still welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this by attaching the alert to the sheet view itself:

```
.sheet(isPresented: $showSheet, content: {
    YourSheetView()
    .presentationDragIndicator(.visible)
    .alert("", isPresented: self.$showDialog) {
        Button("Hello") {
            // button action stuff
        }
        Button("Cancel") {}
    } message: {
        Text("World")
    }
})
```